# Getting the text from the element in iframe with Selenium, Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to get the text in the element, which is within an `iframe`. How can i get the right `Xpath` or `CSS- Selector`? I have switched to the frame, but the compiler is unable to locate the element with `xpath` or `cssSelector`. Probably the problem is that I am contentiously falling to write the right path and selector. All experiments with right click- copy the path or writing the path by myself have no result. 
Here is my code to switch to the iframe and get the text.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-analytics");
 Thread.sleep(10000);

 String st=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='container']/div/div[2]/span")).getText();
 System.out.println(st);
```

here is the html for the element and the element itself
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXhx2.png)

[the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPi4f.png)

Comment: Kindly add the dom snippet

Answer (score 1):

finally this works for me

```
 String st=obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/span")).getText();
    System.out.println(st);
```